# Set Route FrontName dynamically in Controller

Tags: magento2

Is there anyway to override the default front-name inside **routes.xml** and change it dynamically in the controller like `setFrontName(%frontname%)`?

Comment: do want to change it by your self? like from configuration?

Comment: Nono change it dynamically, for example like the "add store code to url" when I have site.com/storecode here I want to change the frontname in storecode dynamically